# Flask site; reuse Javascript/Ajax function for different elements (MacOS Mojave)

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, ajax

I'm not too familiar with Javascript/ajax, but I found a code snippet that works on my flask site.

```
  <script type=text/javascript>
          $(function() {
            $('a#test1').bind('click', function() {
              $.getJSON('/say1',
                  function(data) {
                //do nothing
              });
              return false;
            });
          });
  </script>
```

In my app.py file I have a decorator function that is tied to the JS/Ajax function:

```
import os


@app.route('/say1')
def say1():
    print("background test pass")
    os.system('say -r 100 "I am a robot"')
    return("hello")
```

When an image is clicked, the JS captures the click by id, in this case id=test1, and selects the python function and executes the code (as I'm sure is obvious).

```
<a href=# id=test1><img id=test class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" src="static/macban.jpg"></a>
```

It works great, but I now want to add multiple images and want to reuse both the python function and the Ajax/js function for the different image ids. If anything, the reuse of the JS function would be fine. I know that the 'a#test' is what is selecting which image is clicked, and the $.getJSON('/say1') is the route to the python function, but I haven't found a way to change that depending on click. For now I've resorted to replicating the function (it looks busy and very inefficient).

My specific question is: How to change the 'a#test1' and '/say1' string to the images id when an element is clicked? And if I do create some if/elif logic to decide which is clicked, should it be in the Javascript or Python section?

If there is a better way to do this, feel free to critique me, as I'm new to coding altogether. Oh, and I know that the os.system() is dangerous to execute server side, but this is going to be (for now) a locally hosted site on a secured network. If theres a better way to activate Macs 'say' command from the browser, I'm open to better ideas as well.

Thanks

Comment: You want to be able to run "say" with different values when different elements are clicked?

Comment: Yes, that's the basic gist of it. I have figured out how to do that, but I feel there is probably a better way to interact with the 'say' command with python.

Comment: The way you're doing it is good, it's safe to use `os.system` as long as you don't have *any* external input in there